# PayPal | Auto accept payment made via my cart

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have created my shopping cart, and I have completed the payment process via PayPal.

The problem now is that when I get the payment, it requires by me or the buyer to accept the payment from the PayPal dashboard manualy, in order to be mark the order as completed.

What I would like to ask, is, if there is any way to auto accept the payment, without logging in to my PayPal dashboard.

Can I use the PayPal API to auto accept the payment?

Comment: No problem. I think your problem might be that you only have a Paypal Personal Account, which allows you to manually accept or decline transactions. You might need to convert your account to a Premier or Business account for it to be accepted automatically.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the problem. I am using the PayPal Sandbox, and payments going to a business account. I don't know if there is any PayPal configuration for that issue, or if there is a variable, that must be used with the PayPal API. Also note, that the payment can be accepted either by the client or the merchant. In both cases, if the payment accepted, then the IPN send a "Completed" payment status.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sandbox and your main PayPal account have different configurations, I think PayPal Sandbox specifically holds all payments so you can 'manually' accept them for the purposes of testing, or you may be able to change this in the account settings.

Auto-Accepting payments will work normally on your real paypal account.

It also depends on the configured currency of your Paypal account - if the payment is coming through in a currency you don't ordinarily accept, it will hold the payment as pending. You may need to configure your account to accept other currencies too.